# Bluetooth sound doesn't restore the quality after return closer (linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, bluetooth, thinkpad

When i go too far away from the laptop, the sound quality gets worse, witch is normal. But when i go back, close to the laptop, sound quality remains bad, high-frequency noise and interference remain (not too much, but very noticeable).

I can easily fix it by reconnecting the headphones, even switch pause/play music, or switch the BT profile to HPP and then back to A2DP. But ofcourse, this is annoying behavior anyway.

I already tried ubuntu 20.04 (5.4.0-58-generic) and fedora 33 (5.8.6-301.fc33.x86_64)

Bluetooth service doesn't report any error in logs even in debug mode, dmesg is fine too.

How can I further debug this issue? I would very appreciate any help!

I use Thinkpad t490 and Sony WH1000xm3, if it does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just installed https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt and used new  A2DP Sink: Ldac profile in the blueman.

Problem is gone.